# How implement FocusCycler/FocusTracker in a ckeditor5 plugin

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm developing a plugin using ckeditor5. I did schema, converters, events, commands to insert the plugin block (a table) on editor, and it is working right,  but I'm lost about implement FocusCycler/FocusTracker to change cells focus following a determinate order using **TAB** or **ENTER**. Where I do it? What the best way to do?

Comment: What do you want to iterate over? Editor UI views or some items the edited content?

Comment: I want iterate over editable elements (td's) of my plugin block (table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the tip of @oleq, I found the solution using the Position and TreeWalker classes:

```
import {keyCodes} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/keyboard';
import ViewPosition from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/position';
import ViewTreeWalker from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/treewalker';

editor.editing.view.document.on('keydown', (evt, data) => {
    evt.stop();
    if ( data.keyCode === keyCodes.enter ) {
        let current = editor.editing.view.document.selection.getFirstRange();
        let position = new ViewPosition(current.start.parent);
        let walker = new ViewTreeWalker({startPosition: position});
        for (let element of walker) {
            if ( element.type === 'elementStart' && element.item._attrs.get('editableElement') === 'true') {
                editor.editing.view.change(writer => {
                    writer.setSelection(element.item, 'in');
                });
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`FocusTracker` and `FocusCycler` are not the right tools for you then because these are UI–oriented helpers and you want to move focus in the content.

There's no helper ATM that would make the task easier. You have to add a listener and write your own logic:

```
import { keyCodes } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/keyboard';

// ...

editor.editing.view.document.on( 'keydown', ( evt, data ) => {
    // Use data to learn which key has been pressed.
    if( data.keyCode == keyCodes.tab ) {
        // Learn where the selection is...
        // const range = editor.editing.view.document.selection.getFirstRange();

        // ...

        if ( ... ) {
            // To set a new selection in the next cell
            editor.editing.view.change( writer => {
                 writer.setSelection( ... );
            } );
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your tip was very helpful. I will post my solution below.